# errors validation wordpress (with sidebar in bottom)

Tags: html, wordpress, css, 960.gs

I was just about finishing my website: [www.rikvandoorn.nl/waldorf](http://rikvandoorn.nl/waldorf)

But when i was validating my website i gave a couple of errors, like:

So i was looking at the errors and tried to fix them. i couldn't find the last errors in my code. (i'am using my own theme in wordpress)

**----- update ------**

Ok, the errors are disappeared but i'm still having the issue of the sidebar floating on the bottom.

But it seems wordpress is also conflicting with the 960grid. (zooming in and out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix: try puting `</div>` before `</body>`

But your HTML page looks broken

Comment: Thanks! the errors are disappeared but in IE 7/8 the sidebar is still on the bottom of the page. And how i fix a broken page

Comment: Cause i can just get normal access to my website

Comment: The way HTML is organized is not standard here.. That is why we are having browser issues. If you zoom out the page, you can see the problem more clearly. Someone who know HTML can help you as there is no easy fix for this

Comment: OK thanks, updated the question. with a little bit more info so hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: oh man.. that makes my answer not right.. I think posting a new question for this issue is what is needed

Comment: ok, fixed the zoom function already by deleting a </div> in the header.php